# Advanced Custom Fields - Show Image When True

Tags: php, boolean, advanced-custom-fields

I'm very novice, so please be detailed in your reply! I have an advanced custom true/false field. I'd like for when this field is True, to display a specific image.

For background, I've created loops for a restaurant menu. I want to be able to say "this item is Gluten Free" and the same image/symbol shows up in my loop if the item is checked as "Gluten Free"

I was adding this code but it kept returning an error
My code looks like this - with the real info subbed in

```
<?php if ( get_field( 'field_name' ) ): ?>
<img src="pathlocationofimage.png"></img>
<?php else: ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I was adding this to my functions.php file of my Child Theme. This is the error I got:
Your PHP code changes were rolled back due to an error on line 25 of file /www/wp-content/themes/hello-theme-child-master/functions.php. Please fix and try saving again.

> syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting end of file

Comment: What is the use of the `else:` ? Are you not including anything there? And if not, you don't need it there.

Comment: Perhaps you could show us a bit more code before and after line 25?

Comment: You are adding this to functions.php? how are you calling it? can you show the entire function?

Answer (score 0):

Few things.

- You don't need `else` statement in your code
- You don't need to close img tag

Try this and see if it works

```
    <?php if ( get_field( 'field_name' ) ): ?>
      <img src="pathlocationofimage.png" />
    <?php endif; ?>
```